# Add text box at specific location in report base on value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a cut list generator but I'm having difficulty on the final report.  I'd like to display a rectangle that represents the factory length piece with lines indicating cut points.  In each segment I'd like to have the length of the piece shown.  Using Report.line I've created the rectangles needed but I'm not sure how to get text in each box.  Here is a sample output so far [image: Sample Output]  As an example I want the three rectangles for Piece #1 to have 48" in them, probably all the way to the left.  Any suggestions?  I thought createReportControl might work but I'm not sure that is the correct approach.  I'm also thinking about one text box with a monospace font so I can scale the input across the entire width.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

I played around with the monospace font idea.  It isn't as pretty as I would like but I'm getting closer.
[image]

Comment: I used `CreateReportControl` and made them labels in a similar thing I did, works pretty well.

Comment: You show desired output so what is the issue? What is wrong with that output? Your code is not actually creating that text? What code do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I cannot keep the text in the same spot in each box.  There is one line lower on the page that pushes the number almost out the right side of the box.
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjur0.png)

This code is functional but I'm looking at the cosmetics.  I'm inserting spaces between my values using the following function:

```
Private Function InsertSpaces(CutLen, PieceLen) As String
    MaxChar = 50 ' 6 inch 14pt Courier text box 
    cutchar = Int(CutLen / PieceLen * MaxChar)
    Cutcharcount = Len(Str(CutLen))
    cutchar = cutchar - Cutcharcount + 1
    For i = 1 To cutchar
        InsertSpaces = InsertSpaces + " "
    Next
End Function
```

I'm just trying to clean it up.  CreateReportControl was giving me a error because I wasn't in design mode.  I'm guessing that is because it ran as part of OnFormat of the Detail section.